# Windows 10 - IE 11 Windows Secruity Popup - AutoIT returns no control information

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-11, ui-automation, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am updating a C# Test Framework that uses Selenium webdriver for browser testings.  Upon starting each testcase, I need to bypass the Windows Secruity Popup (IE11 : v11.187.14393.0) in order to get onto the development site i am testing. I have had this working previously using AutoIt with the following code.

```
      AutoItX3 autoIt = new AutoItX3();
      string windowTitle = "Windows Security";

      // Wait 30 seconds max...
      autoIt.WinWait(windowTitle, string.Empty, 30);

      // Need to wait for input fields to load...
      Thread.Sleep(2000);

      autoIt.WinActivate(windowTitle);
      autoIt.ControlSetText(windowTitle, string.Empty, "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", username);
      autoIt.ControlSetText(windowTitle, string.Empty, "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:2]", password);
      autoIt.ControlClick(windowTitle, "OK", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]");
      autoIt.WinWaitClose(windowTitle, string.Empty, 10);
```

I have since updated my OS to windows 10 and the popup box has since changed (See below)

[See new security popup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHDPh.png)

[See old secruity popup example](http://www.enhanceie.com/images/blog/CredUIHTTPAuth.png)

The AutoIt inspector no longer returns any control information for any object within the secruity popup window, so i am unable to interact with them. (See below what he inspector returns for the username inputbox)

> > > > Window <<<<
> > > >         Title:  Windows Security
> > > >         Class:  Credential Dialog Xaml Host
> > > >         Position:   732, 354
> > > >         Size:   456, 386
> > > >         Style:  0x96C80000
> > > >         ExStyle:    0x00200100
> > > >         Handle: 0x00000000015B1204
> > > >
> > > > Control <<<<
> > > >         Class:
> > > >         Instance:
> > > >         ClassnameNN:
> > > >         Name:
> > > >         Advanced (Class):
> > > >         ID: 
> > > >         Text:
> > > >         Position:
> > > >         Size:
> > > >         ControlClick Coords:
> > > >         Style:
> > > >         ExStyle:
> > > >         Handle:
> > > >
> > > > Mouse <<<<
> > > >         Position:   816, 548
> > > >         Cursor ID:  0
> > > >         Color:  0xF0F0F0
> > > >
> > > > StatusBar <<<<
> > > >
> > > > ToolsBar <<<<
> > > >
> > > > Visible Text <<<<
> > > >
> > > > Hidden Text <<<<

I have tried to point AutoIt at the active window and send keys directly but this isnt working either. (See below code).

```
        string windowTitle = "Windows Security";

        // Wait 30 seconds max...
        autoIt.WinWait(windowTitle, string.Empty, 30);

        // Need to wait for input fields to load...
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        autoIt.WinActivate(windowTitle);
        autoIt.Send(username);
        autoIt.Send(Keys.Tab.ToString());
        autoIt.Send(password);
        autoIt.Send(Keys.Enter.ToString());
        autoIt.WinWaitClose(windowTitle, string.Empty, 10);
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get past this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The new dialogue is XAML. AutoIt will only work with Win32 applications. If you want to interact with that dialogue I would suggest using [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx). If you still want to use AutoIt you could attempt to use it to send windows messages to the controls directly but you will need to use another tool to get the IDs of the controls. This forum suggests a [AutoIt script](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/80556-autoit-support-for-wpf-and-net-35-applications/?do=findComment&comment=580026) for sending the windows messages and I suggest Inspect.exe which comes with the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). Inspect.exe is the tool that replaced UiSpy which is mentioned in that forum post.

At my company we had to switch to UI Automation from AutoIt when we went from a VB6 application to a WPF application.